# Facebook is asking to "Complete Verification" after being approved on Business and Publish Pages Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm getting this yellow dot on my previously approved permissions[image]

Is this a common issue?, Both my business and the permissions were approved, so I proceeded to move the app to Live mode.
Is there another step to do ? Is there another thing to wait for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign two contracts.
Go to your Business Manager then to the Business Info section.
Scroll down to the Business Contract.
You'll see the "Supplemental Terms Status" and "Tech Provider Amendment Status".
After the both contracts will signed, you will get the green dot and the Live status.